why my email markup schema has been rejected
We send booking confirmation emails immediately after a customer completes their flight, hotel, or car reservation using our online booking tool (onriva.com). The itinerary details must sync with Google Calendar, ensuring travelers can view their reservations directly within their calendar, and be notified before the travel starts.
we've sent sample emails and submitted forms for flight, hotel and car confirmation emails. the markups were rejected despite all tests were passed and no errors were indicated.
we've run our sample emails through the google email markup tester, and got successful results, with no errors. however, we've got a 'rejected' verdict from the markup review team stating that our markup doesn't meet the criteria:

Event is not added into Calendar automatically.

can you help us detecting what needs to be fixed as all instructions were followed and all google markup tests passed?
thank you!

Is that response not clear? The problem is not with markup but with function. You should debug your code to ensure the requirement of the message is met.

no additional functions were added or required according to the guidelines provided by Google. I appreciate your suggestion to debug the code but this is not helpful.
